Non associativity of geometric algebra??
I can't resolve this bizarreness. First consider this:
$$
\tilde{R}\gamma_\mu R = e_\mu
$$
where $\gamma_\mu$ is a gamma matrix, R is a rotor (exponential of a bivector) and $e_\mu$ is a rotated basis vector.
Now consider the product:
$$
\tilde{R}\gamma_\mu R\tilde{R}\gamma_\nu R = e_\mu e_\nu
$$
However, we know that $R\tilde{R}=1$, because they are rotors. Can I not write
$$
\tilde{R}\gamma_0 R\tilde{R}\gamma_0 R = \tilde{R}\gamma_0 \gamma_0 R = \tilde{R} (-1) R = -1
$$
I do not understand why
$$
(\tilde{R}\gamma_\mu R)(\tilde{R}\gamma_\nu R) \neq \tilde{R}\gamma_\mu (R\tilde{R})\gamma_\nu R
$$
I am sure I am making a mistake, but I do not see what it is.

Why do you think that $e_0e_0\neq-1$?

@user8268 because its supposed to give the metric tensor, no? e_mue_nu gives the metric tensor, no? and in the metric tensor, e_mue_nu can be any real number

@user8268 does R have to be replaced by an element of the General Linear group to yield a metric then?

To be clear, you're using $e_\mu$ to just mean some vector, not, as is customary, a unit-length standard basis vector?

@rschwieb Yeah I thought it would give me a definition of the metric, but from the comments it seems applying $\tilde{R}\gamma_0 R$ just rotates $\gamma_0$ as per SO(3,1), which is then cancelled out by $e_0e_0$ leaving -1 as the answer (same as with $\gamma_0\gamma_0=-1$ directly).

What do you mean "definition of the metric"?

@rschwieb $g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}(e_\mu e_\nu+e_\nu e_\mu)$. I thought transformations by R where enough to define the frame field from $\gamma_mu$.

Do you mean you're trying to see that definition (in terms of $e_\mu, e_\nu$ in terms of $\gamma$ matrices?

It's hard to go back to focusing on coordinates when part of the whole point of geometric algebra is to avoid them.

@rschwieb I thought $g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}(\tilde{R}\gamma_\mu R \tilde{R}\gamma_\nu R+ \tilde{R}\gamma_\nu R \tilde{R} \gamma_\mu R)$

@Anon21 That should be the case, yes.  why do you think it does not?
